# which browser is using openssl

Tags: ssl, browser, openssl

It is said that openssl are widely used, however, as far as I know, the most popular browsers seem not use openssl, instead, they use other SSL libraries like:

- NSS (for all firefox and chrome in Linux)
- SChannel (for browsers in Windows)
- Secure Transport (for browsers in Mac OS X).

Am I right? Or is there any concept I'm taking wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Who said openssl is widely used in browsers? Source?

Comment: I didn't say openssl is widely used in browser, I just heard that it is widely used. So maybe it is mostly used in some server applications, right?

Comment: Apache HTTPD uses OpenSSL, as does OpenLDAP, and Apache Tomcat in certain configurations.

Comment: @ytliu it's probably used in almost any TLS server or client application on Linux except for web browsers. So yes you're right. Was that all you wanted to know or is there some other question hidden between the lines?

Comment: @NiklasB. Thanks. Yes, that's all I want to know. I'm just curious why browsers don't use openssl.

Comment: Your question is rather speculative... The fact that Firefox uses NSS is certainly correlated with the fact both Firefox and NSS are Mozilla Foundation projects. As for Safari (OSX) and IE (Windows), they use their respective proprietary platform implementations, they also happen to be developed by the same company as the one developing the SSL/TLS stack they use. The situation with Chrome may change, see [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=338885) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.tech.crypto/4F3z644W8BM)). Look at Konqueror too.

Comment: Also asked on http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/59184/which-browsers-are-using-openssl with reasonably good answers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL is widely used in web server, according to netcraft survey (http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2015/06/25/june-2015-web-server-survey.html) it can be over 60% of all web servers : Apache with mod_ssl, Google and Nginx. For browser it is just not widely used.